# How to access a custom parameter in next step of optimizer in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I would like to clip the gradient of SGD using a threshold based on norm of previous steps gradient. To do that, I need to access the gradient norm of previous states.

```
model = Classifier(784, 125, 65, 10)

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.1)

for epoch in range(epochs):
        correct, total, epoch_loss = 0, 0, 0.0
        for images, labels in trainloader:
            images, labels = images.to(DEVICE), labels.to(DEVICE)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
            for param in net.parameters():
              if param.grad is not None:
                  param.grad += torch.randn_like(param.grad) * noise_scale 
            optimizer.step()
            current_norm = torch.max(torch.tensor([torch.norm(p.grad, 2) for p in net.parameters()]))
            # Metrics
            epoch_loss += loss
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (torch.max(outputs.data, 1)[1] == labels).sum().item()
        epoch_loss /= len(trainloader.dataset)
        epoch_acc = correct / total
```

I would like to pass the `current_norm` to next step and use it as max_norm for clipping in the next step. How to access this current norm in next step?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have an error? What is happening with your code?

Comment: Hi Ivan, at the very first line it is saying key error for the optimizer state dictionary. I think at very first step it has no value of C_prev from previous state as it is starting of updates. I can initialize with some value; then again come to the same questions how to use the values of previous step from second iterations.